# How to use enum to define a bunch of string consts

Tags: java

any example of using enum to define a bunch of string consts? The string can contains special charaters like - / etc?

Answer (score 2):

```
enum MyConstants {
  STR1("some text"),
  STR2("some other text");

  private String value;
  private MyConstants(String str) {
    this.value = str;
  }
  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

then use it like this:

```
MyConstants.STR1.getValue();
```

Comment: why not `toString()` instead of `getValue()`?

Comment: No particular reason. I'm just showing how you can use enums in a way similar to a regular class, and you can store more than a single property per enum value with the same pattern.

Answer (score 1):

```
String [] messages = {"maybe you", "better go with", "an array?"};
System.out.println (messages[1]);
```

Without further knowledge - why do you like to use enums at all?

Comment: cause they're better. Read this: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html

Comment: Better for what? For storing Strings? Surely not.

Comment: For compile-time type safety - Joshua Bloch

Comment: I don't believe that J. Bloch advertised enums as String-Containers for type safety. Strings are only a surplus for enums, not their main goal. That's why I wrote `Without further knowledge...`. My array might be as inappropriate as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think this page will be helpful:
http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/10/custom-string-values-for-enum.html

In short:

```
public enum MyType {
ONE {
    public String toString() {
        return "this is one";
    }
},

TWO {
    public String toString() {
        return "this is two";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to use enum like this as compared to a class whcih contains a bunch of strings?

Comment: What do you want to do with the Strings? Enums can be used in switch statements, for example and can have methods (that can even be different per enum)